# Pattern rule with different dependencies for different files

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile I have a pattern rule

```
%.out: %.in
        myscript $< $@
```

I want this rule to be triggered not only when the files `quux.in` or `foobar.in` are modified, but also when any of the files `quux/*` or `foobar/*` (respectively) are modified.

How can one express such a dependence in a (GNU) Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.out: %.in $$(call find, $(basename %), *)
    my_script $< $@

find = $(foreach dir,$(1),$(foreach d,$(wildcard $(dir)/*),$(call find,$(d),$(2))) $(wildcard $(dir)/$(strip $(2))))
```

The recursive wildcard `find` function comes from https://plus.google.com/101663514639216293981/posts/h5Xr1i8kgfu.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  You could even have a variable like:

```
DIR_LIST = quux foobar home france china mexico mars
%.out: %.in
    myscript $< $@
$(foreach dir,${DIR_LIST},${dir})/%.out: $(foreach dir,${DIR_LIST},${dir})/%.in
    myscript $< $@ 

OR.....

%.out: %.in
    myscript $< $@
quux/%.out: quux/%.in
    myscript $< $@
foobar/%.out: foobar/%.in
    myscript $< $@
```

Comment: No, because there is not a fixed number of such files and associated directories.

Comment: @gioele How about something like this!? (Check edit above)  Sorry I never got back!....  I got really busy and forgot! lol